# Installing a cpp library on linux

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to install a library (libspopc), but, when I run the make command, I get the errors:

```
strip libspopc.a libspopc.so
strip: 'libspopc.a': No such file
strip: 'libspopc.so': No such file
make: *** [install] Error
```

Working under the assumption that every version of the library I've tried isn't actually missing two of its files, what could cause this? I am running it as su, as instructed, if it's relevant.

Comment: did you run just make `install` or also `make`?

Comment: @klez: one would hope that the `install` rule depends on the build products...

Comment: Are you getting an error before this? Feels like libspopc didn't build right and you're seeing the end of the log instead of where the build error is.

Comment: I didn't call make. Just did, and suggested that I was missing openssl/ssl.h. Installed it, now the make command goes further, but comes to a whole lot of errors along the lines of "undefined reference to `dlopen'", all referring to dlsomething, another stack overflow answer suggested this was due to not linking the library, but surely this wouldn't be the case for another distributed library?

Comment: Anything is possible. Could be a dependency as well. Can't say much without seeing the specific error -- however, check to make sure you have all the dependencies installed (use your favorite package manager) and that you have the Development versions of those available as well. Nothing nearly as annoying as missing a header file for something you think you have installed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this question is only remotely related to programming (seems more like something for superuser.com), on linux you should whenever you can use the package manager of your system. In most cases, it let's you fetch the files as binaries (thus avoiding possible compilation frustrations), keeps your system clean and is (most importantly for me) easy to remove again. Oh yeah, and it helps you keep the library up to date.

Try looking in your package manager! If it's a fairly popular library, it's probably in your package manager's repositiories!

At least I know it's in mine!

```
$ bauerbill --aur -Ss libspopc
AUR/libspopc 0.9-1
    A simple pop3 mail client library
```